# Quadratic equation in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an html page with 2 buttons.
One for first degree equations and on for quadratic.
I have 3 forms for a b and c(quadratic equation)

THe 1st degree equations are solved properly but I can't say the same for the quadratic equations!!!So here is my code:

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Equations</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


</head>
<body class="bg-info">
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center h1">
        Choose the type of equation you want and press =
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-block btn-success" onclick="$('.a').show();$('#c').hide()"> 1st degree</div>
    <div class="btn btn-block btn-info" onclick="$('.a,#c').show();">Quadratic</div>
    <input type="text" id="a" class="a b">
    <input type="text" id="b" class="a b">
    <input type="text" id="c">
    <div class="btn btn-info" onclick="equationType()">=</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my Javascript:

```
function quadratic(){
    var a=$("#a").val();
    var b=$("#b").val();
    var c=$("#c").val();
    var D=b*b - 4 * a * c;
    var base = 2 * a;
    var sD=Math.sqrt(D);
    if (D < 0) {
        alert("Can't be solved")
    }
    else if (D === 0){
        var dx=(b*(-1)) / (2 * a);
        alert("Double solution:"+dx)
    }
    else{
    var x1=-b+sD / base;
    var x2=-b-sD / base;
    alert("X1: "+x1+"  X2: "+x2)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I use that code to solve a quadratic equation the results are not the same as the results I get using my head

Comment: Please add more information regarding what is happening when it does not work. Is there an error or are you getting incorrect values. What have you done to deal with the issue?

Comment: Disregarding the question for a minute, I would note that getting the square root of D and then checking if D < 0 isn't the proper order.  You only need to get the square root of D if D > 0, so at least move that line after the last else.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  I'm assuming you're getting some kind of a response but you're not sure if it's the right one...?  Best thing to do is to test your application by manually figuring out the correct answer and then see if the app does the same??

Comment: No the results for the quadratic equation are not the expected.I tried to solve the same equation with my code and with my hand and the results are completely different

Comment: In that case I suggest you step through your code line by line and check to see where things go wrong.

Comment: Division has higher priority. You should do `(-b+sD) / base` and `(-b-sD) / base`. For example, `(1 + 2) / 10 == 0.3` while `1 + 2 / 10 == 1.2`

Comment: Done. But it's also good idea to parse strings as Brennan suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division has higher priority. You should do

```
(-b+sD) / base
```

and

```
(-b-sD) / base
```

For example, `(1 + 2) / 10 == 0.3` while `1 + 2 / 10 == 1.2`.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value from your inputs, they are strings. You need them to be floats so you can actually operate on them:

```
var a = parseFloat($("#a").val());
var b = parseFloat($("#b").val());
var c = parseFloat($("#c").val());
```

Comment: Not sure what else is wrong, but this is definitely part of the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally division was the problem so here it is:
function quadratic(){
    var a=$("#a").val();
    var b=$("#b").val();
    var c=$("#c").val();
    var D=b*b - 4 * a * c;
    var base = 2 * a;
    var sD=Math.sqrt(D);
    if (D < 0) {
        alert("Can't be solved")
    }
    else if (D === 0){
        var dx=(b*(-1)) / (2 * a);
        alert("Double solution:"+dx)
    }
    else{
    var x1=(-b+sD) / base;
    var x2=(-b-sD) / base;
    alert("X1: "+x1+"  X2: "+x2)
    }
}
```